# in case I won't *

Tags: future, conditionals

A very quick question:

Is it correct to say "**In case** I **won't** be able to watch that"?

If it's acceptable to say that, what type of sentence is it?

**UPDATE**:

As a clarification, I want to say "Can you give me that in case I won't be able to have it later". Probably, it's more a supposition than a conditional.

Comment: I think you mean to say "In **that** case, I won't be able to watch that". Based on the replacement for "If that happens", that is.

Comment: Uhm, not precisely. For example, I want to say "Can you give me that in case I won't be able to have it later". Probably, it's more a supposition than a conditional.

Comment: OK, you may want to edit your question with that fuller context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're mostly concerned about the future tense of "In case I won't be able to" as opposed to "In case I can't". My opinion is that the phrase "in case" doesn't require future tense. For instance, you'd say "I'm taking an umbrella in case it rains." - you would never say "I'm taking an umbrella in case it will rain."

This is based on my own usage of the phrase, however I did find some references: [here (section on tense agreement)](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/9-6.html) and [here ('you can not use the simple future tense after "in case".')](http://www.aulafacil.com/First/Lecciones/Lecc13-G.htm)

I think your sentence should be "Can you give me that in case I can't have it later?"

Answer (score 3):

You could say it that way, sure.  However, I would say that it's more idiomatic (and possibly better grammar as well, I'm not sure) to say "... in case I'm not able to ...".

I believe that it would qualify as a form of [conditional sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence).

Comment: +1. Thanks for your help. Luke Hoffmann described a bit of your answer earlier, but if he doesn't want to put his comment as an answer, I will choose yours. Thanks again!.

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable to say that, but it's not a sentence.
"In case" is not equivalent to "If that happens".
"In case" is equivalent to "If it happens that" or just "If".
[(See the idioms section here)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+case)

It sounds like you are trying to say "If I can't watch that". This isn't a sentence on it's own, but it is a valid condition to begin a sentence.

Comment: Exactly. It's not sentence on its own. As I said to JeffSahol, it's more of a supposition. "Can you give me that (just) in case I won't be able to have it later" I would have thought "If I can't watch that" sounds more natural but I have seen that kind of construction before.

Comment: I didn't properly understand you're question before. You're mostly concerned about the future tense of "In case I won't be able to" as opposed to "In case I can't". My opinion is that the phrase "in case" is a special case that doesn't require future tense. For instance, you'd say "I'm taking an umbrella in case it rains." - you would never say "I'm taking an umbrella in case it will rain." I think your sentence should be "Can you give me that in case I can't have it later"

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot. That cleared that up for me. By the way, I can't accept your comment as you didn't place it as an answer. If you want to do that, I will choose it as 'accepted answer'.