# "Stay in touch in case you will" — possible?

Tags: grammaticality, future

Is the following sentence correct? I am not sure about the future tense after the "in case". Tried googling but could not find any phrase like that..

> I would like to stay in touch in case you will be looking for someone like me next year.

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43264/in-case-i-wont).

Comment: Obligatory remark: there is no future tense in your sentence, and so [all is fine](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/91130/300).